# How to upload the multiple zip files to FTP Server(FileZilla) Using SFTP Sampler in JMeter

Tags: javascript, groovy, file-upload, performance-testing

I am upload the single zip file at a time to FTP Server if I increases the thread number to 5 it will runs five times but I can see only one in the FTP server

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're uploading the same file to the same folder - the previous version will be replaced by the most recent version so your 5 threads are writing to the same file and you're seeing the result of the latest upload only.

The solution would be to use different file names for different threads using [__threadNum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) like:

[image]

this way the files will appear as:

```
somefile-1.zip
somefile-2.zip
etc.
```

so the current thread number will be added to the filename

However on subsequent executions the files again will be replaced so you can use unique names using [__UUID() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID) like:

```
somefile-${__UUID}.zip
```

this way you will get filenames looking like:

```
somefile-0f573e42-c93a-4952-8378-2bdd34b44019.zip
```

Check out [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) article for more information on JMeter Functions concept.